# Hidden Panel in Source Tree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I'm having trouble on how to show a panel in Source Tree which is shown below and indicated by red box. I have spend about 30 minutes and i have no idea how to show it. I'm currently using version 1.9.6.2.

I was using it before and after i have committed my work, the panel is gone all of a sudden. Please help.

[image: This picture is only taken from google]

Comment: Perhaps this link helps: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/9874707/sourcetree-how-to-show-sidebar-

Comment: did my answer help? did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's collaped, search it with your mouse, in the left panel and you will find it eventually.

Comment: Yes, it was just collapsed. The panel got so thin when collapsed.